# Check if the users has logged in

Tags: php

I have a website which enables user to login. 
And the problem is how do I check if they are `logged in.`
I tried this method- when the user logs-in update (user table) row `Logged` into '1'  and when they log out update `logged` row back to 0. This is done by getting username from `session`

```
 $username=$_SESSION['username'];
```

However this method does not work because it only works for one user. I read somewhere `timestamps` is a good method to implement but im not sure how to do it.

Any help? thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't this method work?

Comment: it works when the first user logs out. When the second user logs out it stays 1 instead of 0

Comment: Keep in mind that each user will have your own session.

Comment: True with session start(); right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fill your `$_SESSION['username']` with the username after successful login, this is your check if this variable is not empty.

A php session is determinted trough the PHPSESSID as query param or in a cookie (if enabled) so a session should be unique per browser and client and last until the browser is closed.

For time limited session you can save the logintime as a timestamp in session variable (ex. `$_SESSION['logintime']`) and automatically logout the user, if the timestamp is too much in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just tested in two different browsers it worked!